# My properties sidebar has disappeared

Tags: interface

[image: .]

It disappeared when I entered a few wrong keys while following a tutorial, but I can't remember what.

Comment: you have to select an object...(that's why there is "nothing selected")

Comment: It's toggled with the 'N' key, but as @Chris says you'll have to have an object selected to show any settings on the Item tab.